# Search duplicate entries in List<TextBox> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list containing TextBox controls. Basically all this grouped inside a groupbox control.

```
List<TextBox> listTextBox;
```

I need to check for any duplicate entries within these TextBoxes  whenever the groupbox validation event is invoked.

I can only think of the boring way is to loop through the list sequentially and parse the textbox value each time and find if there is more than one entry with the same value.

Can any one help me by using a Predicate to do the same operation more efficiently.

For ex:

```
list.Count(//predicate that gets the value for all textbox);
```

if the count is more than 1, Then I'm sure there are duplicate entries in the textbox.

Is there any other better way ?

Cheers
VATSAG

Comment: Do you want to enlist all the duplicate texts?

Comment: Either enlist or if the count is more than 1 (hint for duplicates) would do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` and then filter the groups with a `Count` > 1 and select the `Key` for all such texts. I have not complied the code but this should be close enough.

```
var duplicateTexts=
        listTextBox.GroupBy(tb => tb.Text)
            .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
            .Select(group => group.Key);
```

Comment: This predicate would give me the key of the duplicate entry. But is there a way to get just the count ?

Comment: Simply do .Count() of the duplicateTexts ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can get key and count both, while traversing.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly something like this may work.

```
var duplicates = listTextBox
        .GroupBy(i => i.Text)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => new {Count = g.Count(), 
                          Name = g.Key});
    foreach (var d in duplicates)
    {
        var keyName = d.Key;

        var count = d.Count;
    }
```