# LINQ assistance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

I have 10 textboxes in my winform.

For performing some validation, I use the OnValidating event handler for doing some processing. For the sake of convenience I have added all these textbox controls in an IEnumerable collection.

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> txtBoxList;
```

Inside the OnValidating eventhandler, I need help with LINQ query to get all the **current values** of the textboxes in the form of string collection

i.e. `IList<string> contentList;`

Now, my requirement is to get values of the textbox(non-empty) as a string collection. I want to make use of LINQ.

This query I used, is returning me only distinct values

```
contentList = txtBoxList.GroupBy(t => t.Text)
                        .Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Key))
                        .Select(grp => grp.Key)
                        .ToList();
```

i.e., if textbox1 and textbox2 is having the same content,

```
ex: textbox1 : "John" and textbox2 : "John"
```

then it returns only one occurrence of "John".

I need your assistance to get all the values of the textbox (***including duplicates***) inside string collection

Awaiting response 
VATSAG

Comment: Just removed group by method call.

Comment: `txtBoxList.Select(bx => bx.Text)` - something along those lines?

Comment: What have you tried? I had answered a similar question of yours yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466402/search-duplicate-entries-in-listtextbox-using-linq/29466497#29466497

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand correctly then you want

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                               .Select(tb => tb.Text);
```

Find all controls on your form that are textboxes, select those that arent empty, and get the text

What you may want to do though, is add textboxes to a panel first, and then find the textboxes on that panel..

```
panelName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()....
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
contentList = txtBoxList.Where(t => t.Text != null)
                        .Select(t => t.Text)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: The above query will include the empty strings in the results which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by the text, e. g. "john", "john", "doe", "bla" will become "john", "doe", "bla" because you are grouping identical strings.

You can simply do:

```
contentList = txtBoxList.Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g))
                        .Select(t => t.Text)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: @JenishRabadiya thank you for the correction. Also; I changed the order - this will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
contentList = txtBoxList.GroupBy(t => t)
                        .Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Key))
                        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1))
                        .ToList();
```

This will list all the duplicates.